# Unit testing for service with multiple API calls in parallel using Karma and Jasmine / Angular 8

Tags: angular, api, testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit tests (Jasmine and Karma) for a service and a component whose aim is to perform two API calls to the Star Wars API (more info at https://swapi.co/) with two different `URLS`, to get people and starships data. Both calls are returned simultaneously with a `forkJoin`.

My `App` component calls the `ApiService` to perform two calls as follows:

APP COMPONENT:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from '../services/api.service';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

onGetData() {
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe((data: any) => {

      this.peopleData = data[0];
      this.starshipData = data[1];

     });

  }
```

API SERVICE:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    const randomPeoplePage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    const peopleUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=${randomPeoplePage}`;

    const randomStarshipsPage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    const starshipsUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/starships/?page=${randomStarshipsPage}`;

    const peopleProm = this.http.get(peopleUrl);
    const starshipProm = this.http.get(starshipsUrl);

    return forkJoin([peopleProm, starshipProm]);

  }
}
```

I am fairly inexperienced with testing, especially on how to test API calls properly. 
I have been trying different solutions for the past couple of days, something like this:

```
 it('should return an Observable', () => {
    const randomPeoplePage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    const randomStarshipsPage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;


    const dummyData = [
      {
        count: 87,
        next: `https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=${randomPeoplePage + 1}` || null,
        previous: `https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=${randomPeoplePage - 1}` || null,
        results: new Array(87)
      },
      {
        count: 37,
        next: `https://swapi.co/api/starships/?page=${randomStarshipsPage + 1}` || null,
        previous: `https://swapi.co/api/starships/?page=${randomStarshipsPage - 1}` || null,
        results: new Array(37)
      }
    ];

    service.getData().subscribe(data => {
      expect(data.length).toBe(2);
      expect(data).toEqual(dummyData);

      const peopleReq = httpMock.expectOne(`https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=${randomPeoplePage}`);
      const starshipReq = httpMock.expectOne(`https://swapi.co/api/starships/?page=${randomStarshipsPage}`);

      forkJoin([peopleReq, starshipReq]).subscribe(() => {
        expect(peopleReq.request.method).toBe('GET');
        expect(starshipReq .request.method).toBe('GET');
      })

      peopleReq.flush(dummyData[0]);
      starshipReq.flush(dummyData[1]);

    });


  });
});
```

but this test isn't passing and I am really not sure why or what should I look into. 
Do I need to test the API calls in the `api.service.spec.ts` or in the `app.component.spec.ts`? 
How do I simulate the return? Should I test them singularly?
This is an 'academic' test, therefore any hint for best practice is welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **component** should contain **logic** that is concerned with the **presentation** of the data. Now, you could have both **Smart** and **Dumb** components.
For **Smart** components, you could test the **interaction** with **external services** that provide data(store, route, a service that provides data), whereas for **Dumb** components you could test if the **data** is **displayed properly** and/or if `@Output` events are sent properly.

A **service** should contain **business logic**(api calls, maybe storing data etc...), logic that is not directly concerned with data presentation.

In this case, I'd simply provide some predefined data for the `getData()` so I ensure that I won't call the *real* API.

```js
  it('....', () => {
    const url1 = 'url1';
    const url2 = 'url2';

    const responseMap = {
      url1: { data: 'url1' },
      url2: { data: 'url2' }
    }

    // Assuming this is imported..    
    class ApiService {
      constructor (private http) { }

      getData () {
      }
    }

    const getSpy = jasmine.createSpy('Http.get').and.callFake((arg) => {
      return of(responseMap[arg]);
    });
    const mockHttp = { get: getSpy }
    const apiService = new ApiService(mockHttp);

    spyOn(apiService, 'getData').and.callFake(function () {
      return forkJoin([this.http.get(url1), this.http.get(url2)])
    });

    apiService.getData()
      .subscribe(([r1, r2]) => {
        expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url1);
        expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url2);

        expect(r1).toBe(responseMap['url1']);
        expect(r2).toBe(responseMap['url2']);
      })
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am analyzing what happens at the line `const apiService = new ApiService(mockHttp)`: you are calling `ApiService ` passing `{ get: getSpy }` as argument; My understanding is that this argument will be passed to what is inside the `Class` constructor, (`(private http)`): is this correct? What type is that `private http` in the constructor? In my code is rendered as `Unused field`. Just trying to make sense of all this. THANKS

Comment: Yes. I wouldn’t pay much attention to the ApiService class since, in my case, it’s just for explanation purposes. In your original ApiService, you inject the httpclient. Instead of letting the angular DI framework to resolve the dependency for you, you’re doing it yourself in order to provide a mock object so you can make your assertions eventually.